# Is it possible to publish a photo to a users feed on facebook using js?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
var params = {};
params['type'] = 'photo';
params['name'] = 'Cool photo!';
params['description'] = 'Hello facebook!';
params['link'] = 'http://www.example.com';
params['picture'] = url;

FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', params, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    console.log(response.error);
  } else {
    alert('Published to stream!');
  }
});
```

Currently returns the response '(#324) Requires upload file'. I have done some reseach and realize this is because the request requires 'multipart/form-data' for the photo data. Is there a way to do this using js?

NOTE: Yes, I want to upload a photo, full size.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999024/facebook-graph-api-upload-photo-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some experimentation with it just now, and I have also failed to manage to make a file upload using the Facebook Javascript SDK.

I also did some reading on line, and I stumbled upon this question here at stackoverflow.com: [Facebook Graph API - upload photo using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999024/facebook-graph-api-upload-photo-using-javascript)

The general consensus on this that I've gathered is that it's best to use the Facebook PHP SDK or some other means, due to the `multipart/form-data` that you quite rightly noted.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I want the user to upload a full-size photo.

Comment: Darn, it seems that Frederick Behrends managed to beat me to that post, but it's definitely worth a quick read.  You'll be glad to know that from a personal perspective, the PHP SDK is quite a delight to use!

Comment: Trying to integrate it smoothly into a backbonejs system but I guess we will have to use the PHP sdk.