# Upload ByteArray image on Facebook with Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, arrays

I'm trying to upload a photo on Facebook using Javascript SDK.
In particular I generate a base64 encoded bytearray from my Actionscript3 app, I pass it to Javascript file using ExternalInterface, and from that I decode the bytearray and I try to upload to FB. But it give me this error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException","code":324}}
```

I tried to upload an image simply from url, and in that way it goes well!

This is my Javascript code:

```
    upPhoto:function(photo) {
       var img = F.decode_base64(photo);

       FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
        message:'test',
        fileName:'test',
        image: img
       }, function(response){

          if (!response || response.error) {
            log('Error!');
          } else {
            log('Upload OK!');
          }
       });  
    }

    decode_base64:function(s) {
       var e={},i,k,v=[],r='',w=String.fromCharCode;
       var n=[[65,91],[97,123],[48,58],[47,48],[43,44]];

       for(z in n){for(i=n[z][0];i<n[z][1];i++){v.push(w(i));}}
       for(i=0;i<64;i++){e[v[i]]=i;}

       for(i=0;i<s.length;i+=72){
          var b=0,c,x,l=0,o=s.substring(i,i+72);
          for(x=0;x<o.length;x++){
            c=e[o.charAt(x)];b=(b<<6)+c;l+=6;
            while(l>=8){r+=w((b>>>(l-=8))%256);}
          }
       }
      return r;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got that parameters list from, but according to the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) there's no *fileName* nor *image*, you should use *source* which is required.

Another thing is that you need to post this as *multipart/form-data*, which you don't.

Have you checked this thread: [Facebook Graph API - upload photo using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999024/facebook-graph-api-upload-photo-using-javascript)

Comment: I used that parameters in AS3-facebook-api and there worked!
How can I encode the bytearray image in multipart/form-data? 
The thread you linked me is not helping me so much.

Comment: The action script sdk is not an official one (as far as I'm aware), and they might "abstract" some things for you. If it works for you with the AS3 sdk, then use that.

Comment: I had some issue with login callbacks so, after many failed attempts, I decided to switch on Javascript SDK..but also for that I'm discovering problems..
My goal is to post some pictures generated from actionscript on Facebook in a stable way. Maybe the unfailing way to interact with FB is the PHP sdk?

Comment: I'm not fully aware of your situation, but if the uploading works in AC3 and the login part works with JS, then just use the js for login and the AC3 for uploading... You can of course use a server side, but then you're complicating things again.

Comment: I will try this one! The only thing that make me doubt is if AS3 and Javascript takes separate inizializations/data to works..I'll try!

Comment: Let the JS SDK to do most of the work, then when you need to upload a pic just take the access token from the JS (using external interface) and upload the pic, you don't even need to use the AS3 SDK, just issue a POST to the graph url.

Comment: It's possible to upload pictures through POST request (to the graph url) as byte array? Or the _source_ must be an URL?

Comment: No, the "source" is not a url, that's something completely different. the "source" should be the actual bytes of the pic, as "multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 2):

I've spent hours and hours the last 3 days on this topic.
Now, I got it, and i've got a SOLUTION to fix your code (you were close to the solution.. ^^) :

**That is SIMPLE :** Once your user has authorized your fb app with "publish_stream", I just use the following code, and it does upload the picture on the user wall :-)
I hope it really really helps !

```
            <a href="#" onclick="uploadonwall(); return false;">Call the Publish Magic</a>
            <script>
            function uploadonwall(){
                FB.api('/me/photos', 'post',
                {
                    message: 'A new pic is on my wall ...',
                    url:'http://www.yourwebsite.com/big_image_about_to_be_published_on_facebook_user_wall.jpg'

                }, function(response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert('Oops! User Denied Access');
                    } else {
                        alert('Success: Content Published on Facebook Wall');
                    }
                });
            }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved using Facebook JS SDK for login stuff, and simple Actionscript's HTTP functions to POST image on Facebook.

This is the AS3 upload function:

```
private function uploadOnFB(event:Event):void {

    var byteArray:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(videobitmapData);

    var url:String = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos";

    var param:Object = new Object();
    param.message = "My uploaded photo!";
    param.access_token = access_token;

    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    urlRequest.url = url;
    urlRequest.contentType = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + UploadPostHelper.getBoundary();
    urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    urlRequest.data = UploadPostHelper.getPostData("photo.png", byteArray, param);

    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
    urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
}
```

`access_token` is returned by `onLoginSuccess` callback of the FB Javascript SDK.

Comment: were you able to get a message to post along with the image? I'm finding it's not carrying my message? But have seen in other places that you can't post a message with an image anymore..? Is this true?

Comment: @Lagoo87 what message do you mean? If you mean the message shown in the image post ("My uploaded photo!" in the example above), it is correctly posted.