# Post photo to facebook page using javascript and graph api

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook JavaScript sdk to post photo to some fan page.Here's my code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  action="https://graph.facebook.com/<page_id>/feed" target="ifram_name">
      <input name="source" type="file" style="font-size:13px;" />
      <input type="hidden" name="to" value="113342002047830"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="access_token" value="user_accesstoken"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="type" value="photo" />
</form>
```

It says "**missing message or attachment**".

I have also tried changing "action" to "https://graph.facebook.com//feed"
but photo is then uploaded to user's album.

Can anybody tell what is missing in my code ?

Comment: Here is your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999024/facebook-graph-api-upload-photo-using-javascript

Comment: I want to post photo on some fan page's wall, not uoload in my own album

Answer (score 2):

You should use `photos` connection of [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos), [`page`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos) or [`album`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/#photos) (not the `feed`) and supply active `access_token` for user/page.

```
<form action="https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/photos"
      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="source" type="file">
  <input type="hidden" name="to" value="113342002047830"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="access_token" value="user_accesstoken"/>
</form>
```

You can read more details in (year old) blog post [How-To: Use the Graph API to Upload Photos to a user’s profile](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/).

Please note that this will upload the file but your application/code will not be notified on this and user will see response like this:

```
{
   "id": "1001207389476"
}
```

If this isn't desired use server-side technology to upload photos. Another option is to use JS-SDK with `url` parameter:

```
FB.api('/PAGE_ID/photos', 'post', {
  url: 'http://example.com/image.png',
  message: 'Upload demo'
}, function(response){
  if (response && response.id)
    console.log('Photo uploaded', response.id);
});
```

**Update:**
Please note that you should use page's `access_token` to be able to post to page's wall, if you provide `access_token` for user photo will be uploaded to user's application album regardless of `to` parameter. See [Authenticating as a Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) on details how to get the `access_token` for page.

Comment: I need to upload photos on 'Pages', not in my or someone else's 'Profile'.

Comment: @MohdQasim, it doesn't make it anyhow different from what I've posted... Actually code samples I've provided are the same for users and pages just replace `PAGE_ID` with desired page/user id

Comment: I have already mentioned that "/page_id/photos" places the photo on the user album not on page's wall(I don't know why)

Comment: @MohdQasim, because you are using user's `access_token`, not the one for `page`. See [Authenticating as a Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) for more details how to get one.

Comment: I am not the admin of the page.I just want to mimic the facbook photo post behaviour.When we post photo to facebook they are not added to albums, they are just shown as a wallpost

Comment: is it possible to share local image  like url: 'image.png',