# How to upload video on facebook using FB.ui Javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I'm using FB.ui method to post image to facebook as described below:

```
FB.ui({
    display: 'popup',
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'image',
    link: 'link',
    picture: 'image path',
    caption: 'caption',
    description: 'description'
}, function(response){
   // do something
});
```

I'm able to post image successfully, but couldn't post video. I have tried, but failed.

```
FB.ui({
    display: 'popup',
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'link',
    picture: 'thumbnail image path',
    source: 'https://example.com/media/video.mp4',
    caption: 'caption',
    description: 'description'
}, function(response){
    // do something
});
```

above approach is posting feed, I'm looking video should play on facebook only instead of taking link of page.

I am not sure whether I'm missing something on video post OR approach it self wrong.

Could someone help on video, I would really appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can upload videos to Facebook, using the Graph API, in multiple ways. You can have *resumable* and *non-resumable* uploads.

The latter is the easiest; you post to *graph-video.facebook.com* and the video data must be `multipart/form-data` encoded. The files are limited to **1GB** in size and **20 minutes** long.

You can [upload videos using the SDKs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/#Creating). For example, the following code will use the JS SDK:

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/{user-id}/videos",
    "POST",
    {
        "source": "{video-data}"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Here the `source` parameter is your encoded video file. See the docs for more info. Alternatively, if the video is already uploaded somewhere, you can use the `file_url` parameter to provide a link to that video.

**Please note:** the JS SDK default to *graph.facebook.com*, but you need to post to *graph-video.facebook.com*. So either you need to override the domain, or re-create the post with a normal JS http request. In that case, use the `source` parameter *and* add your `access_token` in a parameter with that name.

If you have more control over your video files and the process, you can upload the files in [chunks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads#resumable). That will allow you to recover from lost upload segments, without the need to re-upload the whole file.

Comment: what if we want to show progress bar during the large video upload how we can do that in the browser using JavaScript api.?

Comment: The link you are referring to, doesn't that require authenticating the user first, get an access token and such? How can I upload a video without obtaining a access token, just like sharing on youtube but then actually uploading the video instead of sharing a link.

Comment: Which permission is needed to make this request? I am asking my users to give me `user_videos` and `publish_video` permissions but even then I receive a `(#100) No permission to publish the video` error when making a post request. My FB application is in development mode and I am testing with the admin user of that application. The documentation that is linked in the answer is silent about required permission to post video to user timeline.