# Upload photo to my facebook album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way to upload photos to my existing facebook album with the javascript SDK without any authorization ? For example, I know my facebook ID and the image URL what I want to upload.

Comment: Why the need to do it unauthorised?  at least, if say it was a one off, why not use graph api explorer to get an accesstoken and then do it?

Answer (score 0):

Without authorization you cant upload images to an facebook album.

Take a look at this answer:
[Facebook Graph API - upload photo using javascript on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999024/facebook-graph-api-upload-photo-using-javascript)