# Photo upload with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to upload photo via Facebook graph API in Javascript. I have php file in which i have all the necessary stuffs which uploads photo to users wall and album too. What i really need is that i want to call the upload script with javascript `onclick` without refreshing the current page. I have a function -

```
function uploadPic() {
    $.post("http://myURL.com/upload/index.php", { cover: "{/literal}{$p.PID}{literal}" } );
}
```

I was wondering how to run the actual url - `http://myURL.com/upload/index.php?cover=1` which successfully uploads the photo to users wall. What i am planning to do is upload photo to users wall silently without loading the current page and when the onclick event is called, Opens a dialog box which say user that the photo was uploaded successfully to their wall. Need suggestion/ help with the JS script.

Thank you.

Comment: google perhaps can help?

Comment: Tried google. But it didn't helped.

Comment: Give a bit more context. It looks like you only need to call a url via ajax. What's your php script? Calling it with $.post and get the result back should do the job.

Comment: I found a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file

Comment: another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999024/facebook-graph-api-upload-photo-using-javascript