# How to encode a file from the file system as multipart/form-data?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, winjs, multipartform-data, facebook-winjs-sdk

I want to let users upload photos to Facebook in my image viewer app. As seen in this post, [Facebook Graph API - upload photo using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999024/facebook-graph-api-upload-photo-using-javascript), I have to encode my photos as multipart/form-data to be able to upload them. How to archive this encoding on `Windows.Storage.StorageFile` items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open that photo (of type `Windows.Storage.StorageFile`) for reading, convert it's stream to blob, append it to `FormData` object and upload using whatever Ajax library you want  (`WinJS.xhr`, `jQuery.ajax` etc).

Following code illustrates it better than words:

```
file.openReadAsync().done(function(fileStream) {                
   var fileData = MSApp.createBlobFromRandomAccessStream(file.contentType, fileStream);
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('upload', fileData, file.name);

   ... // send formData as xhr request body
});
```