# Upload a video using Facebook API for Tizen?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, facebook-graph-api, tizen

I wondering how to upload a video using Facebook API with Tizen application which is developed in HTML5. Can any one say how to integrate..?

Answer (score 1):

The code inside the widget should be like any other JavaScript implementation of a video upload to Facebook for an example see: [Facebook video upload via Graph API Javascript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094828/facebook-video-upload-via-graph-api-javascript-sdk)

The only caveat should be that [any resource that it is accessed outside should be declared(see Accessing External Network Resources):](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/accessing_external_network_resources.htm)

> You cannot access external network resources by default (WARP: W3C
>   Access Requests Policy). So, you must request permissions for the
>   widget to retrieve network resources. You can enter several URLs by
>   using the Add button on the Access tab. For each URL, you can indicate
>   if you want to allow the widget to access the URL sub-domains. The
>   Allow subdomain column contents can be toggled by mouse clicks.

so it cannot work without having access to the resource needed in our case defined in `config.xml`:

```
<access origin="https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/videos" subdomains="true"/>
```