# Facebook access for Tizen platform (using JS)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, tizen, tizen-web-app

For my application on Tizen I need to make Facebook integration(be able to login and post to the wall some statuses).

But I couldn't use FacebookJS SDK because i need to set up domain URL. Unfortunately for Tizen I don't have any URLs, because it's not a classic Web application.
I can't use `http://localhost` as domain name because Tizen app has URL like `file://some/location/app`.

Does somebody try to integrate Facebook to Tizen app?

PS. here the link with workaround https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/social-network-services-tizen but example doesn't work, because deprecated facebook API returns some Error.

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this issue in Tizen app? I'm stuck with this one too :\

Comment: nop, it was enough for me to use regulart URL to show facebook dialog for sharing content  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Did you try using window.open?? I'll call this as dirty fix. I set my redirect url to google.com and initiated the facebook oAuth in new window with window.open method. When the oAuth is complete facebook will redirect to google with access token. By monitoring the url of the window opened, i close the window when the access token is available in url and bring the app back to my page. note: i didn't use facebookJS SDK

Answer (score 3):

As redirect url you can use standard facebook webpade in this situations https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html and after login succes you have to read parameters from redirect url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also `http` resources but you need to define `access` element in `config.xml` manifest file to have access the needed resource.

See the answer I gave here for reason and details:
[Upload a video using Facebook API for Tizen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751734/upload-a-video-using-facebook-api-for-tizen/14829203#14829203)

Comment: my config.xml has no restrictions for access. I have `<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>`. If you have some example of using facebook(like posting to wall), could you share it somehow? Thanks!

Comment: @aklokov I don't have or code a facebook app but for the code I wrote that was the problem that happened.