# uploading video to facebook with javascript, without php

Tags: javascript, facebook, video, upload

How do I upload a video from a server to Facebook, with javascript/jquery/ajax, but without using php?

I tried calling:

```
 FB.api('/me/videos', 'POST', { source: url, name: title }, iCallback);
```

but this is returning an error: "(#353) Missing video file".
I checked the url, and it's valid and directs to a valid video file on the server.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possibly similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264599/facebook-new-javascript-sdk-uploading-photos-with-it (This answer contains a way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5455783/323659)

Comment: saw that post earlier. it deals with photos, not videos. i think there is a difference in the fields required in the api

Comment: Did you add the "@" sign to the beginning of the path to the video in the source parameter?

Comment: Lix - i tried adding the "@" sign, but got the same result. could you point me for an example using @ in file names from server (not on the local machine)?

Answer (score -1):

Try using "file_url" instead "source".