# upload a LOCALLY HOSTED photo to Facebook with the JS SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am aware you can upload photos to facebook via the JS SDK provided an external photo URL.  But how do I upload a locally hosted photo to Facebook? If I use my IP address I still get this error:

```
"http://10.0.1.9:9914/media/images/templates/cover/851x315_FLAME.png is an internal url, but this is an external request
```

code:

```
var data = array();
data['message'] = 'hello world';
data['url'] = 'http://10.0.1.9:9914/media/images/templates/cover/851x315_FLAME.png';

FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', data, function(response){
    if (!response || response.error) {
        //alert('Error occurred');
    } else {
        //alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
});
```

all I want is to be able to upload locally hosted photos to FB using the JS SDK! please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264599/facebook-new-javascript-sdk-uploading-photos-with-it).

The iFrame upload approach is probably your best option but then if you have the room to do that then you might as well just do it all on the server-side?